# Javascript Exception "parameter name : index" using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

As stated in the title i get the subsequent exception using jquery : 
"parameter name : index" 
this happened sometimes when this javascript code is executed :

```
$.post ( url , parameter , function (data) {
         $.each ( JSON.parse(data) , function (index, value) {
                console.log ( value.toString() ) ;
         }
       }
);
```

Has anybody an idea about the cause of this exception, unfortunately it happened on a pc where i cant debug it (is not under my control).

EDIT : 
i have corrected the typo parmeter, console.Write instead is a semplification to hide some interaction with some Devexpress components (that is OffTopic IMHO)

To be more precise there is not a console.log command but a clientList.AddItem ( value.toString() ) that is pretty equivalent (i hope).

Comment: `console.Write` what is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `parmeter` without the a (don't know if it's wanted)
and `Console.Write()` which is kind of C# console application :)

in JS you need to use `console.log` and you should also check if `console` is defined (you can get problems with IE)